# Checking if a string is present in various columns. If present change another variable in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am trying to use a condition row by row and if true change a variable in my dataframe row by row.

Here is some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'grade' : [1,2,3], 'new_grade': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'pred1': ['yes','no-x','no'], 'pred2': ['yes-x','yes-x', 'yes'], 'pred3': ['yes','no-x','yes']}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

```
   grade  new_grade pred1  pred2 pred3
0      1        NaN   yes  yes-x   yes
1      2        NaN  no-x  yes-x  no-x
2      3        NaN    no    yes   yes
```

In the example if there is not an 'x' in any of the pred1, pred2, or pred3 I want the 'new_grade' to stay the same. If every variable in pred1, pred2, or pred3 has an 'x' I would like to subtract 1 form 'grade' and save that as the 'new_grade'.

I tried this but it does not give me the desired result:

```
df['new_grade'] = np.where('x' not in str(df[['pred1', 'pred2', 'pred3',]]),  df['grade'], df['grade']-1)
```

This is the desired output:

```
   grade  new_grade pred1  pred2 pred3
0      1          1   yes  yes-x   yes
1      2          1  no-x  yes-x  no-x
2      3          3    no    yes   yes
```

Not sure if I would have to maybe do a for loop using iterrows()?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I messed up the desired output. It is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `df.filter` to get all the `pred` columns and check if they contain a `x`. Then use `np.where` to conditionally substract 1 from `grade` with `.sub`:

```
m = df.filter(like='pred').apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('x'), axis=1).all(axis=1)

df['new_grade'] = np.where(m, df['grade'].sub(1), df['grade'])
```

**Output**

```
   grade  new_grade pred1  pred2 pred3
0      1          1   yes  yes-x   yes
1      2          1  no-x  yes-x  no-x
2      3          3    no    yes   yes
```

Output with `NaN`:

```
   grade  new_grade pred1  pred2 pred3  pred4
0      1          1   yes  yes-x   yes    NaN
1      2          1  no-x  yes-x  no-x    NaN
2      3          3    no    yes   yes    NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work if lets say I added a pred4 that has just np.nan? Is there a way to get the same result adding in that column?

Comment: Yes, see edit @Jake. The method `.all` skips `NaN` by default, see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your case we can using `contains`

```
df['new_grade']=df.grade-df.loc[:,'pred1':].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('-x')).all(1)
df
Out[591]: 
   grade  new_grade pred1  pred2 pred3
0      1          1   yes  yes-x   yes
1      2          1  no-x  yes-x  no-x
2      3          3    no    yes   yes
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work if lets say I added a pred4 that has just np.nan? Is there a way to get the same result adding in that column?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```py
cond1 = df.pred1.str.endswith('x')
cond2 =  df.pred2.str.endswith('x')
cond3 = df.pred3.str.endswith('x')
df['new_grad'] = df['grade'].where(~(cond1 & cond2 & cond3), df['grade'] - 1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work if lets say I added a pred4 that has just np.nan? Is there a way to get the same result adding in that column?

Comment: @Jake, depends, if you are not taking into account this new column, then the solution should work just fine